# Selenium plan to scrape images with captions

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Many images on most websites come with caption, either as `alt` text (most common), or some other attribute in the tag. However, many images come with nothing, and just a normal text node (`div` or `span` or `p`) located nearby (generally at the bottom, but sometimes, top, left or right as well) serves as visual caption for the image.

Example - this image [here](https://cricclubs.com/CambodiaCricket/viewTeam.do?teamId=180&clubId=37563): as you can see has no caption, as part of the image, but there is an `h4` node positioned below that serves as visual caption (player name):

[image]

That **"Doc Danith"** is the name of the player, or an apt caption for the image, is understandable easily when viewed in webpage, but impossible from the image as there is no alt text there containing that name, and the caption text can be anywhere, in an entirely separate text node altogether, so the link between that and the image is not possible to figure out from the HTML alone.

Is there a way Selenium can be used here? May be it can be trained on few thousands of such cases where they can capture an image and relevant caption, and then it be let to scrape web pages finding which text piece is the most likely candidate to be the caption for an image in the entire page?

Challenges:

1. Selenium is pointed at tags and elements, here the element itself is not guaranteed. It has to to be determined at runtime visually, and "captured", and then the most relevant text piece should also be "captured". How can it be done? Is it possible? Some examples similar to this idea?
2. Is there some existing ML models out there that can be used for such a task?

Comment: Yes it's possible.  No, it won't be easy. When you say "maybe it can be trained" you're implying using AI to modify Selenium code on the fly.   If you are able to create this, it would still not work 100% of the time.  I think you'll want to refine your requirements as it's not likely you are searching the entire internet here.

Comment: You'd need to share a lot of examples but - one option that springs to mind is using a `following` xpath after the image. Something like it `//img/following::*[not(text()='')][1]`  - that xpath will get the first node of any type (ignore the tree) after the image where the text is not blank. It seems to work on this page - i get the `p` after your post and i get the meta about `SexyBeast`'s rep and badges.   If you want to know more i can share a more detailed answer - this is just a quick comment in passing. This might be able to be refined further with `parent` and `normalize-space` too.

Comment: Hi @RichEdwards that sounds very promising, please proceed for an answer. Of course, the main challenge is the tree, there can be literally no relation between the caption and image, their common parent may go really high up (here for the example it goes ups to 2 levels I think), and the second challenge being, the caption can be on the left, right or top as well.

Comment: I believe captchas were invented to solve this sort of thing (it was to help digitize books)... but if you could provide a widely used service where the human input was to type in the caption(s) you could use that to "train/model" the AI.  (tie the image with the markup of the whole page + css + js)

Comment: @SexyBeast - i've checked that following xpath with the site you mention and it returns more than just the name. It returns a lot of whitespace and also "Batter" which is good; but it also takes content after EVERY image - including header images and team logos.  Maybe we need to take a step back. You're trying to correlate images and text. Why? What's your overall goal here? What's this information for?  There could be another solution approach your requirements. -  a general xpath would be a quick soluution but it won't be a one glove fits all solution for every page going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium 4 has a new feature which allows you to find element by [relative locator](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/#relative-locators). The best method in your case would be [`near`](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/#near).

> If the relative positioning is not obvious, or it varies based on window size, you can use the near method to identify an element that is at most 50px away from the provided locator. One great use case for this is to work with a form element that doesn’t have an easily constructed locator, but its associated input label element does.

So it allows you to iterate over images and check nearby texts.
with this snippet:

```py
elems = driver.find_elements(locate_with(By.XPATH, "//*/h6|//*/h5|//*/h4|//*/h3|//*/h2|//*/h1|//*/p").near(image))
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.text)
```

unfortunately, you cannot change it's search range from 50px.
Another method is to implement near function by yourself.

The following code finds all texts (h1,h2,...,p) and their locations and then iterates over images and check if the text is near the image.

`width_thresh_low`, `width_thresh_high`, `height_thresh_low` and `height_thresh_high` are the limits for images to avoid unrelated images like website's logo.

`top_extra_pixel`, `bot_extra_pixel`, `left_extra_pixel` and  `right_extra_pixel` are search range. For example, in this website, labels are below the images, so it's logical to make `bot_extra_pixel` greater than others.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.relative_locator import locate_with

width_thresh_low = 200
height_thresh_low = 200
width_thresh_high = 1000
height_thresh_high = 1000

top_extra_pixel = 20
bot_extra_pixel = 150
left_extra_pixel = 20
right_extra_pixel = 20

# path to chrome driver
service = Service(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
options = Options()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get("https://cricclubs.com/CambodiaCricket/viewTeam.do?teamId=180&clubId=37563")

# find all images
images = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "img")

# find all headers and paragraphs
text_elements = driver.find_elements(locate_with(By.XPATH, "//*/h6|//*/h5|//*/h4|//*/h3|//*/h2|//*/h1|//*/p"))
text_elements = list((elem.text, elem.location['x'], elem.location['y'], int(elem.value_of_css_property('font-size')[:-2])) for elem in text_elements)

for i, image in enumerate(images):

    width = int(image.get_attribute("width"))
    height = int(image.get_attribute("height"))

    # check if image is appropriate
    if width_thresh_high >= width >= width_thresh_low and height_thresh_high >= height >= height_thresh_low:

        # method 1
        # elems = driver.find_elements(locate_with(By.XPATH, "//*/h6|//*/h5|//*/h4|//*/h3|//*/h2|//*/h1|//*/p").near(image))
        # for elem in elems:
        #     print(elem.text)
        # print("***********************")

        # method 2
        out = driver.execute_script(f'return document.getElementsByTagName("img")[{i}].getBoundingClientRect();')
        bot = out['bottom'] + bot_extra_pixel
        top = out['top'] - top_extra_pixel
        right = out['right'] + right_extra_pixel
        left = out['left'] - left_extra_pixel
        # print(bot, top, left, right)
        texts = ""
        min_font_size = 999
        for text, x, y, font_size in text_elements:
            if top <= y <= bot and left <= x <= right:
                # print(text, x, y, font_size)
                if font_size < min_font_size:
                    texts = text
                    min_font_size = font_size
        image.screenshot(f"./output/{i}.png")
        with open(f"./output/{i}.txt", 'w') as file:
            file.write(texts)
```

This is the result of the code running with method 2. It finds nearest text to the image with the smallest font size.

[image]

**How to automate thresholds and extra pixels**

At this stage, the only part of the code that is variable depend on the website you are crawling, are thresholds and extra pixels values. It's hard to configure these variables by html. Based on what category you are crawling, you can use a word dictionary to automate this process. For example, you know that the website you are crawling is about sport and the information you are looking for is players names and their positions. Based on them you can write a code to change thresholds to find only texts that contain name or related sport position.

Comment: Hi Ali. Thanks a lot. This looks very promising. Our problem is - we are crawling a massive amount of content, so no way will we be able to detect what works best for which websites. So in general, we have to choose the text at the shortest possible distance in all 4 directions. Edge case - the a paragraph ends on top of image, then image comes, then caption, and then a new paragraph starts below, both caption below and paragraph above look like equally near candidates, in which case, we have to choose the text with the smaller font size (either direct or inherited, basically computed).

Comment: @NedStarkOfWinterfell , Updated the code. now it checks all the texts near to the image but only keeps the one with smallest font size. It checks font size with `int(elem.value_of_css_property('font-size')[:-2])`. The `[:-2]` is used to get rid of `px` at the end of font-size value.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really opened up a new way of doing it for us!

Answer (score 1):

Mentioned in the comments - Not a full answer but a starting point.

A way of jumping the DOM tree structure is to use `following`. This ignores the tree level you're at currently and finds the next match after the event.

The MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes) is a good reference for this and other xpath axes.

With the xpath mentioned in the comments: `//img/following::*[not(text()='')][1]`

This matches more than you'd expect. It's ANY image ANYWHERE and the the first element with text after it.

On the website mentioned in the question, it hits this block (noting that is match 10 of 40!):
[image: image from question]

The text content on that highlighted node is:

```
'\n                                                \tDok Danith \n
Batter\n                                             View Profile \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
```

So, it seems to work here.
The "meta" about the image is Dok Danith & batter. You just have extra junk that needs clearing out.

#################

In the comments you also mention the alt/meta can be to the side of the image or above it.

There is a 'preceding' xpath axes which, as you can guess, goes up the DOM ignoring the structure.

Perhaps a solution isn't one xpath but a couple?
One xpath gets nearest preceding text, one gets nearest following with text.

Record both then you can review and filter as you need.

Comment: That sounds promising, Rich. Can you provide another example to cover that, basically the code should be covering both, since there is no way one can know in advance where the caption can be for each of the millions of images that can come up while crawling the web.

Comment: Like, for example, look at this URL: https://sports.ndtv.com/cricket/ind-vs-pak-live-score-asia-cup-2023-india-vs-pakistan-match-live-updates-on-reserve-day-4378637#News_Trending, and look at the first pic in the main page. There is a caption below it - "India vs Pakistan Asia Cup Highlights: India outplayed Pakistan by 228 runs.", but immediately above, there is some garbage text as well. In absence of that garbage text, the last line of the para on the top - "Pakistan by 228 runs" could have been considered equally close as the caption at the bottom. How to filter them out?